# Create object on Jbutton click

Tags: java, swing, jbutton

I am trying to create an object when the user presses the button.So far, I've come up with the implementation bellow, but it does not seem to work.I haven't been dealing with Swing and Java UI at all so I am guessing it might be an amateur mistake.

The object I am trying to create is from another type called DebitCard.

```
private JFrame frame;

public static void main(String[] args) {
    EventQueue.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
        public void run() {
            try {
                GenerateCard window = new GenerateCard();
                window.frame.setVisible(true);
            } catch (Exception e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
    });
}

public GenerateCard() {

}

{

    frame = new JFrame();
    frame.setBounds(100, 100, 450, 300);
    frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
    frame.getContentPane().setLayout(null);

    JButton btnNewButton = new JButton("Generate card");
    btnNewButton.setBounds(112, 213, 216, 41);
    frame.getContentPane().add(btnNewButton);

}

private class buttonEvent implements ActionListener {

    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
        String command = e.getActionCommand();
        if (command.equals("Generate card")) {
            DebitCard a = new DebitCard();
        }

    }
}
```

Comment: You have the "buttonEvent" but you didn't set it to your "btnNewButton".. So it will not do anything

Comment: Java GUIs have to work on different OS', screen size, screen resolution etc.  using different PLAFs in different locales.  As such, they are not conducive to pixel perfect layout.  Instead use layout managers, or [combinations of them](http://stackoverflow.com/a/5630271/418556) along with layout padding and borders for [white space](http://stackoverflow.com/a/17874718/418556).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Based on your available code, you seem to have forgotten to register `buttonEvent` with `btnNewButton`

```
btnNewButton.addActionListener(new buttonEvent());
```

You might want to take a closer look at:

- [How to Use Buttons, Check Boxes, and Radio Buttons](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/components/button.html)
- [How to Write an Action Listener](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/events/actionlistener.html)
- [Laying Out Components Within a Container](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/layout/index.html)
- [Code Conventions for the Java TM Programming Language](https://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/javase/documentation/codeconvtoc-136057.html) (this will make your code easier to read and it easier for you to read others)